# How do I link ASP.NET membership/role users to tables in db?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design, forms-authentication

I am going to use forms authentication but I want to be able to link the asp.net users to some tables in the db for example

If I have a class and students (as roles) I'll have a class students table.

I'm planning to put in a Users table containing a simple int userid and ASP.NET username in there and put userid wherever I want to link the users.

Does that sound good? any other options of modeling this? it does sound a bit convoluted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the ASP.NET membership service creates a `GUID` per User, so if you need to have a foreign key of the user in a table, then this is what you should use. As such, you will not need the mapping table of a username to a userid as you already have a unique identifier per user (the aforementioned GUID)

If your looking to extend the amount of information one can store against a user, then this [link](http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/security/tutorial-08-cs.aspx) has all the details regarding that.

Comment: sounds good I'll accept the answer, I was thinking in more puritan manners :) not to alter asp.net tables directly or link directly.. but I guess that is an accepted practice given the article you linked.

Comment: I personally had the same thoughts, but actually ended up dropping the ASP.NET forms auth and just ended up rolling my own db solution in tandem with the DotNetOpenAuth library.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use ASP.NET membership, you should create the users with the ASP.Net Membership classes and database tables. This will create a user in the **dbo.aspnet_Membership** with the appropriate roles set for that user, upon successful insertion into this table, you can get the **UserId** from the **dbo.aspnet_Membership** table.

In YOUR Users table create a table with an int(auto-incrementing) ID, and also create a membershipID field in your table(rather than username) of type **uniqueidentifier** called say, **membershipID**. This is where you would store the value from the **aspnet_Membership** table to link the two together. You should also put a foreign key relationship on your **membershipID** field for referential integrity.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify with the other posts, id is of type **GUID** in your ASP.NET code, and of type **uniqueidentifier** in your SQLServer database.

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a system where we retro-fitted forms authentication into a system using another authentication system.  We added a column to our existing user account table.  We added a GUID column, since this is what the aspnet_xxxx tables use,  and filled it with the GUID from the aspnet tables.  We then wrapped creation of our entry in our table into a transaction dependant upon the success of account creation using the asp.net membership calls.  It's very important to make sure you sync the tables together with a transaction or something to make you don't have entries in one system and not in the other.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that usernames can change so you shouldn't use that to link your systems.  Use the GUID.

Hope this helps